# How to Load CSV to array with object names

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to be able to store the the data in my CSV files so I can read it easier and serve it to a webpage.

The CSV is in the following format, probname1:"meat1", probename2:"meat2".......

If I paste the data in manual like https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_array_object
it works,
I also tried setting up my array dirrentely and using MGot90's method from [Read CSV headers using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22331886/read-csv-headers-using-javascript)

But I can only ever call 1 full value of each object e.g settings[0], and not call the object by its name e.g settings["ProbeName1"] 
I want the following to beable to output meat1 with the following in the CSV file.
updatevalues.csv = probname1:"meat1", probename2:"meat2"

```
loadData();
function loadData() {
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
parseCSV(this.responseText);
}
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "js/updatevalues.csv", true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

function parseCSV(string) {
var allTextLines = string;
var settings = [];
var settings = allTextLines.split(",");
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = settings["ProbeName1"];
}`
```

currently I can only get id=demo1 to output ProbeName1:"meat1" using settings[0].
If I use settings["ProbeName1"] it will display undefined.

Answer (score 1):

This function will convert your csv into a JSON object:

```
function parseCSV(str) {
    var allTextLines = str;
    var settings = [];
    var settings = allTextLines.split(",");
    var results = {};
    var name, val, idx;
    for (var i = 0; i < settings.length; i++) {
        idx = settings[i].indexOf(':');
        name = settings[i].substring(0, idx);
        val = settings[i].substring(idx+2, settings[i].length-1);
        results[name] = val;
    }
    return results;
}
```

Working in fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p3t7Lv28/

That code strips the quotes off the values by using idx+2, length-1

Comment: Thanks worked, I spent a few weeks trying to get this to work :)

Answer (score 0):

Why you need that i dont know but may be you can use [SheetJS](http://sheetjs.com/demos) tool.Its for showing the excel on the web.